# Stuck while parsing XML using Xpath

Tags: java, xpath

From the below mentioned xml I need to extract the value of tag dp:result and store it into a string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
            <dp:timestamp>2015-07-09T04:45:15-04:00</dp:timestamp>
            <dp:result>OK</dp:result>
        </dp:response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I am using this code to do it. where Resp is a string containing the above mentioned xml

```
    XPath xxPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/env:Envelope/env:Body/dp:response/dp:result";
    String Status = xxPath.compile(expression).evaluate(Resp);
    System.out.println(Status);
```

However I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Node
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.dp.client.HTTPSClient.main(HTTPSClient.java:337)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your expression, below code is working:

```
public class XPathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("file.xml"));
        XPath xxPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/Envelope/Body/response/result";
        javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression cc = xxPath.compile(expression);
        String result  = cc.evaluate(doc);
        System.out.println("Result:: " + result);
    }
}
```

> output

```
Result:: OK
```

And here is my Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
            <dp:timestamp>2015-07-09T04:45:15-04:00</dp:timestamp>
            <dp:result>OK</dp:result>
        </dp:response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```